# Entity Framework Code First - objects all inherit base class, how to exclude records with a disabled property

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, inheritance

I have a bunch of DTO objects that all inherit from a DtoBase class with some properties like Id, CreatedDate, and Disabled.

```
public class MyAppContext : ApplicationDbContext
{
    public DbSet<A> As { get; set; }
    public DbSet<B> Bs { get; set; }
}

public class A : Base
{
    public bool LikesMilk { get; set; }
}

public class B : Base
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Base
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Disabled { get; set; }
}
```

When it comes time to querying the DB, is there an extension method or something I could write in order to exclude all disabled records on all queries for all objects?

```
//both should exclude disabled records
db.As.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LikesMilk)
db.Bs.ToList()
```

Comment: The typical method would be to build a view in SQL that returns only enabled rows, then have EF link up to the view.

Comment: You need primary keys, would you just put one on the base class?

Comment: Putting the primary key in the base class adds it to all inheriting classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using this NuGet package EntityFramework.DynamicFilters and it was really easy to implement.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters

```
using EntityFramework.DynamicFilters;
public class MyAppContext : ApplicationDbContext
{
    public DbSet<A> As { get; set; }
    public DbSet<B> Bs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Filter("IsDisabled", (Base x) => x.Disabled, false);
    }
}

public class A : Base
{
    public bool LikesMilk { get; set; }
}

public class B : Base
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Base
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Disabled { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Definitely use this instead of doing it yourself like I posted above.

Comment: I started down your path then decided to google some NuGet stuff. This seemed a lot cleaner.

Comment: Have you done any performance profiling to see how it affects queries?

Comment: I have not gotten to that point yet, no, but I am planning on doing so. I will report back.

Answer (score 2):

I've done this pretty much the same way that is outlined in this article.  http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/soft-deleting-entities-cleanly-using-entity-framework-6-interceptors.html

Essentially, you create an attribute to designate a column as your "IsDeleted" column (in your case, Disabled).  Then you create an interceptor that does 2 things:

- Intercept delete commands and change them to updates
- Intercept all queries and filter out soft deleted entities.